# Which modern IDE to choose when working with Oracle database on Windows?

Tags: database, ide, oracle-database

Good afternoon!

I am working with Oracle Database (mostly writing queries, stored procedures and creating tables). The problem is that I can not find a modern IDE to work with Oracle such as Visual Studio Code (I want to have code autocompletion option, automatical code checking, useful code color schemes etc as VScode does).

So far I have tried:

- PL/SQL Developer - good one, but code assistance is awful.
- SQL Developer - not so much difference with PL/SQL Developer.
- DBeaver - the same story.
- JetBrains DataGrip: I can not use it due to corporate restrictions.
- Oracle and PL/SQL add-on for Visual Studio Code: nice one, but exxtremely slow (simple select * from table execution takes 20-30 seconds here and less than 1 second in PL/SQL Developer).

So I am looking for something like DataGrip or Visual Studio Code add-on for Oracle and PL/SQL. I understand that my question is off-topic, but I really do not know where else I can ask such a question (if you could provide me such a source, I would be very grateful).

I am working on Windows, no Powershell.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you already take a look at [Toad for Oracle](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle)? You didn't name a price tag or license specifics, so it's hard to tell which "corporate restrictions" kept you from Jetbrains. Toad is used frequently in corporate environments.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at Toad. My company doesn't buy Jetbrains' licences but I can consider any other software (paid or free).

Comment: Your Question should specify those "corporate restrictions".

Answer (score 0):

**[Toad for Oracle](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle)** might fit your needs:

- **working with Oracle Database:** yes
- ''writing queries, stored procedures and creating tables:** easily, either directly via SQL or guided by its GUI
- **code autocompletion option:** yes
- **automatical code checking:** to a degree (e.g. syntax check)
- **useful code color schemes:** yes
- **working on Windows:** yes

[image] [image]
<sup>Screenshots: code editing (with test cases), code optimization (source: [Toadworld](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using Toad for more than 10 years now at various customers, though mostly in context of my DBA duties. It works well. Due to its many features, it takes a little time to get used too, though: you'll be able to work with basics (running SQL, browsing your schemata) pretty soon – but certainly will find a new feature which was "hidden in plain sight" every week for a while.

[image] [image]
<sup>Screenshots: Team Coding, Automation Designer (source: [ToadWorld](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/?); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Toad does not come for free, it rather uses a kind of subscription service. When I last checked the licenses it was a one-time fee valid for all updates of the current major version (e.g. if you buy Toad 15, you'll receive all updates for Toad 15.x but need to upgrade to Toad 16 if you want to use that – though you're not forced to but can stick with 15 if you prefer); now it seems to be a yearly fee. Prices start at around 500 € for a basic license and reach up to around 1.700 € for the "XPert Plus License" and beyond, per year (you might be interested in the [Developer Edition](https://shop.quest.com/682/purl-toad-for-oracle-term-editions), which currently comes for about 1.500 € per year). Each higher license includes more options.

Comment: Is it possible to search across code with Control + F in Toad? Does it highlight table alias or table name in the code when your mouse cursor is on the specific table alias or table name?

Comment: I rarely use Toad for coding, as pointed out. But yes, you can e.g. hold the `Crtl` key and click an object name (e.g. table name) to go straight to its definition. `Crtl`-`F` works on the open file, but IIRC there was also a way to search all open tabs (never used that, so I'm not sure). And no, it's not exactly "cheap" ;) It has a free trial, though, so you can check first, so you don't have to "buy a pig in a poke".